# Screen recording in Windows 8 makes PC unusable?

Tags: windows-8, screen-recorder

OS used: Windows 8 Pro x64

Hi there,
I got a weird problem. I tried to record my screen using different screen recording applications like Camtasia7, Hypercam, and some others.
So if I hit "record" everything works fine for about 3-4 seconds. Then the PC slows down heavily caused by extremly high IO usage. The PC gets nearly unusable and laggs like hell. I can't switch applications, can't get TaskManager with Ctrl+Alt+Del, or something else without waiting 1-3 Minutes.

After about 5-8 Minutes and a bit of luck I am sometimes able to end the process of the recorder and IO calms down very slow(100% IO lasts for about 2 Minutes before becoming normal).

I don't know why this happens. Screen recorders that support Windows 8 aren't out afaik but at least Camtasia7 worked with Windows 8 Developer Preview and Windows 8 Release Preview (only had to change record method to .avi). No slow downs or something else.

Is there anyone out there who knows this problem too? Is there maybe a solution to this problem?

Comment: The problem is heavy I/O, so disable things that use I/O. Antivirus (and malware protection), Search Indexer, etc. Also drop the quality settings down. You don't need to record cinema quality sound and video.

Comment: I don't have any heavily I/O using applications running in the background. Quality etc. is at default. I just installed Win7 as dual boot and recorded the video with Win7 instead of Win8.
On Win7 there are the same conditions as described above and it worked fine. Hope it is only a bug and not a problem with my Laptop.

Comment: with that information, I'd look at the drivers being at fault. That's the only difference between the two. Check your motherboard drivers specifically.

Comment: Are any of the recording programs compatible with W8, what do the authors say?

Comment: No they aren't officially compatible with W8, but they worked with W8Previews too.
@RandolphWest: Unfortunately I got a Sony Vaio AW-Series (it is a bit older) and Sony doesn't deliver any new drivers for my laptop. Maybe I will find something but I gave up my hope in this case a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

So Camtasia is now officialy compatible with Windows 8. They also pushed an update recently that you should try.

Check out the site at http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia-system-requirements.html

I believe this is a local problem, as it seams to effect multiple independent programs?

Comment: I will test it. Maybe it works now :)

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work :( Maybe it is really a problem caused by my hardware.