# When Windows 8 says a program needs to be reinstalled to work, is doing a Repair good enough?

Tags: windows-8

I upgraded to Windows 8 Pro last night from Windows 7 Home Premium. Everything went smoothly, however, Action Center reports that Camtasia Studio 7 and Pinacle HD 14 need to be reinstalled in order to run properly on Windows 8.

My question is do I need to uninstall those programs and reinstall them, or will simply running the repair option for those installers be enough to satisfy the reinstall requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repair wont help. It will still give you those messages.

You should definitely uninstall the programs first and then do a fresh installation.

Comment: You are right. I had to fully uninstall both programs, then reinstall. After that, my messages went away.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, the repair option would attempt to try and get the program running. It wouldn't even try to reinstall the program.

My suggestion would be to try the repair first and the reinstall second.

Answer (score 0):

The number of people reporting problems with Camtasia is quite high. I would definitely recommend a clean install, if not simply a version upgrade.

See [Screen recording in Windows 8 makes PC unusable?](https://superuser.com/questions/494815/screen-recording-in-windows-8-makes-pc-unusable/496785#496785)